# Unity - Getting Player Input

Tags: unity-game-engine, key

I am making a basic game in Unity and needed to know how to get the input of a player.  When I searched this up, I got the same result on every website saying me to put in a line of code.

I tried putting in this line of code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScrScrScrScrScr : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Square;
    private MeshRenderer myRenderer;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("Space key was pressed.");
        }
    }
}
```

This did nothing and each time I pressed space nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with that code. Did you put this script on a GameObject in your scene? Are you looking at the console to see if it's spitting out the Debug? Finally... what is up with the class name?

Comment: Yeah I was being stupid and did not add the script to an object, thank you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).